# Name conflict inside a class when there's multiple inheritance of interfaces containing the same method name, but different return types

Tags: typescript, oop

I have two interfaces, A and B, and they both have a function named `myFunction`. Interface A's function has a return type of `void` and interface B's function has a return type of `string`.

When Class C implements both A and B (multiple inheritance), there is a conflict in class C since we can’t have to implement two functions named `myFunction` with different return types. What is the correct approach to implement/avoid such patterns?

```
interface A {
  myFunction: () => void;
}

interface B {
  myFunction: () => string;
}

class C implements A, B {
  myFunction() {
    console.log('asd');
  }
  myFunction() {
    return 'asd';
  }
}

new C().myFunction();
```

Comment: ive chosen to go with composition instead of overloading because it will allow us to implement both methods separately instead of combining logic. composition is better than extending an abstract/concrete class that implements one of the interfaces and then also implementing the other interface directly (following design patterns principles)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

You only just do logic in one function for all abstract method that inheritance from interface and use `function overload` at here. Read more [Function overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```
interface A {
  myFunction: (val: string) => void;
  otherFunc: (val: string, options: string) => void;
}

interface B {
  myFunction: (val: number) => string;
  otherFunc: (val: string, options: string, otherParam: any[]) => string;
}

class C implements A, B {
  otherFunc(val: string, options: string): void;
  otherFunc(val: string, options: string, otherParam: any[]): string;
  otherFunc(...args: any[]): void | string {
    // args may be is [val, options] or [val, options, otherParam];
    // business logic depend on args and check args[2] (otherParam) for doing more thing.
    if (args[2] && args[2].length > 1) {
      // implement business logic for interface B
    }
    return '';
  }

  myFunction(val: string): void;
  myFunction(val: number): string;
  myFunction(val: string | number): void | string {
    // business logic depend on val
    return val ? console.log(val) : val.toString();
  }
}
```